# Euler number of the world sheet

Tags: string-theory, gauss-bonnet

I have a question in the section 3.2 "The Polyakov path integral" in Polchinski's string theory p. 83.
Given

> $$ \chi=\frac{1}{4 \pi} \int_M d^2 \sigma g^{1/2} R + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial M}  ds \,\, k \,\,\,\, (3.2.3b) $$

It is said

> We have noted $\chi$ is locally a total derivative in two dimensions and therefore depends only on the topology of the world-sheet -- it is the Euler number of the world sheet

I have two questions related to this sentence...

1) Where did the book note that $\chi$ is locally a total derivative?

2) Does the Euler number for $\chi$ come from the Gauss-Bonnet theorem? I never learned that theorem in my differential geometry course :( and Eq. (3.2.3b) is in different form with [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) 
by different factors $\frac{1}{4\pi}$ and $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ (why? convention of normalization?). Would you recommend any reference for the proof of Gauss-Bonnet theorem for physicist?

Comment: because I want to be consistent with the convention in Polchinski's book. The equation is under ">". Therefore, any possible inferior notation used in the book is in responsibility of the book itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler number (often called the [**Euler characteristic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Polyhedra)) is given a in terms of nice integral formulas in the Gauss-Bonnet theorem, but it can be defined in other ways.  The difference in the factors simply comes from the fact that the two-dimensional scalar curvature $R$ is twice the Gaussian curvature $K$ (see towards the end of the first paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature)).  Since you're reading Polchinski, you'll probably have no problem with most proofs of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem (which are all over the internet), but I think Do Carmo's differential geoemetry has a rather nice, elementary proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By the way, how to see $\chi$ is locally a total derivative (question 1) ?

Comment: @user26143 I don't know.  I'd consider posting that as a math.SE question.  I think it's a rather subtle business after doing a bit of google searching and reading.  It's not even clear to me exactly what the mathematical content of that statement is.